# woocommerce api add product with custom id

Tags: api, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to add products from another system into WooCommerce using the API while maintaining the old system's `reference id`.

The other system has a unique key for each product which I would like to use for accessing the products in WooCommerce through the WooCommerce API.

**What would be the easiest way to do this?**

I'm considering repurposing the `slug` field in Woocommerce to hold the old system id and then doing a filter on that when retrieving products. Is this an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the slug field like I suggested in the question above and it's working fine.

Would recommend this approach to others, as it allows your key to be accessible via the API.

Comment: can you please share you postman collection for the post method for add product- if you check my question i am able to get result with get method but for post method its not working using - HTTP